# How can I dismiss the view appeared by touching Add item in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have added add(+ symbol button) button to my navigation controller.
 When I click it a view appears from bottom. I added a navigation bar and two buttons to it.

One save and one cancel button. And the view have one textEdit box. After editing I can save or cancel. If I touch cancel I need the view to disappear like it should go down again.

I think all iPhone , iPodTouch users use it. Like when they touch Add item then a view appears from bottom and when they cancel it goes down again. How can I make in this way in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're talking about a **UIActionSheet**?!?

http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html